# What is the preferred way of importing object hierarchies into Python

Tags: python, object, import

I create a class Animal in a file animal.py

```
class Animal():
    pass
```

I create a child class Dog in file dog.py

```
from animal import Animal

class Dog(Animal):
    pass
```

If I run dog.py now, everything works.

Because these two classes are so incredibly useful, I now want to use them in my new project.

So I create a subfolder ./lib in my new project
and copy the two files in here.

**ProjectFolder:**

- main.py
- lib/

  - animal.py
  - dog.py

Now want to use the Dog class in my main.py.

```
from lib.dog import Dog

sparky = Dog()
```

Aaand it doesn't work anymore because the Dog class can't find its Animal parent class.
I guess because in sys.path[0] is now the path of main.py.

What is the correct approach here?

The two files animal.py and dog.py should of course work in every new project without having to adapt them every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will start organizing your code into `modules` and `packages`: you already have the modules which are your `.py`, and you will create packages based on your directories to use to import the modules you want. The [official python modules and packages doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#) will help you a lot with this.

For your case a good place to start is to setup a main package and then a package for your `lib`:

```
main-package/
   __init__.py
   main.py
   lib/
      __init__.py
      animal.py
      dog.py
```

- The `__init__.py` can be empty, it is just required so that Python understands that the directory that contains it is a package. We are saying that both the `main-module` and the `lib` are packages.
- With the `main-module` as package whenever you add a sibling directory to `lib` you can import directly with `from main-package.lib.dog import Dog`, which is called an **absolute import**
- If you keep the `main.py` at the main package level like it is on my example above you can keep doing like you are currently with `from lib.dog import Dog`, since they are within the same package
- Now you should be able to import `animal` from `dog` with: `from lib.animal import Animal` or `from .animal import Animal`

Another reference: [the import system python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Hope that helps.